# Getting Error while updating the records in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, service-broker

I am getting error when  **updating therecord** in *sql server*, below is the error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 74, Procedure tr_dbo_Devices_b4c88d6c-c452-44cb- 
bb4d-8e317a8703f7_Sender, Line 140 [Batch Start Line 4]
Invalid object name 'dbo_Devices_b4c88d6c-c452-44cb-bb4d-8e317a8703f7/StartMessage/Update'.
```

I have enabled service broker and written one sample code using `sqltabledependency` on "Device" table. Whenever I am updating this table I am getting above error. Is there any fix for this or any problem with my `sqltabledependency` code?

Comment: Can you post the SqlTableDependency code you've written, please?  Just so we can see how you've set that side up.  It doesn't have to be exactly the code, perhaps a stripped-down version of it.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens primarily due to database context mismatching.  When people open SSMS, they usually do not notice that their default database context is set to master in most of the cases. You just need to change the database context to whatever database our current object is and everything will start working immediately.

Comment: thanks for reply, but it is not the case as you suggested..its no where or near to problem..